# customize delete button function of cgridview

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have two table:

*menu*:        id, name

*category*:     id,name, menu_id

here, category table have menu_id foreign key.

**relation of menu models**

```
'mnuCategories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MnuCategories', 'menu_id'),
```

customizing delete button of CGridView

```
array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}{delete}
            'buttons'=>array
            (
                 'delete'=> array(
                            'click'=>'js:function()',
                             )              
            ),
        ),
```

here I want to customize delete operation by checking if child record exist or count child record. If count is greater than one then alert user 'cannot delete! child record exist'. if count is zero then allow user to delete with confirmation message.

Answer (score 1):

In your model add [beforeDelete() function](http://yii.codexamples.com/v1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeDelete-detail)

```
protected function beforeDelete() {

parent::beforeDelete();

/* 
* Check children
* 1. if (0 > $count > 2) return FALSE;
* 2. if ($count == 1) return TRUE;
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put a beforeDelete() function in your model and check your logic there and return FALSE if you want to prevent deletion.